# Get a state value in navigationOption?

Tags: react-native

I've a value in a state(currentLocation), I want to keep it in the right side of the navigation bar. How can I do that?
Using this.state.currentLocation is not allowed in navigationOptions & gives undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this4.state.currentLocation) error

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      (this.state = {
        currentLocation: null
      });
    this._getCurrentLocation();
}

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Search',
    headerRight: (
      <View>
          <Text>{this.state.currentLocation}</Text> //this can not be done, how to get the currentLocation value in the headerRight?
      </View>
    )
  });

  _getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    this.setState({
      currentLocation: await AsyncStorage.getItem("currentLocation")
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is by using [`setParams`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams).

```
componentDidMount () {
    this._getCurrentLocation()
}

static navigationOptions = ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Search',
    headerRight: (
      <View>
          <Text>{navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.currentLocation}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  });

_getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    const currentLocation = await AsyncStorage.getItem("currentLocation")
    this.setState({currentLocation}, () => this.props.navigation.setParams({currentLocation}));
  };
```

Comment: hi, it gives undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.state.params.currentLocation) error. However using const { params = {} } = navigation.state; and params.currentLocation worked

Comment: Updated, as it is undefined initially.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, because I currently have nothing to test with but you should be able to retrieve a state value like this:

```
import { store } from "./App"; // Where you create your redux store

const currentLocation = store.getState().currentLocation;
```